# Python flask rest api

Tags: python, mysql, rest, api, flask-restful

i like to add a rest api to my project and therefore I need a selective mysql statement bt I always get back

{
    "error": "(1054, u\"Unknown column 'None' in 'where clause'\")"
}

Whats wrong with the code? how do i need to escape id correctly in the mysql select syntax??

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_restful import reqparse
from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL



mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)

# MySQL configurations
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'pi'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'xxxxxxxx'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'xxxxxxxx'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'


mysql.init_app(app)

api = Api(app)

class test(Resource):
    def post(self):
        try:
        # Parse the arguments

        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('ID', type=str, help='Id of Item')
        args = parser.parse_args()

        id = str(args['ID'])
        conn = mysql.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `PowerSystem` WHERE ID=$(id)")



        data = cursor.fetchall()

        items_list=[];
        for item in data:
            i = {
                'ID':str(item[0]),
                'Timestamp':str(item[1]),
                'batteryVoltage':str(item[2]),
                'batteryCurrent':str(item[3]),
                'solarVoltage':str(item[4]),
                'solarCurrent':str(item[5]),
                'loadVoltage':str(item[6]),
                'loadCurrent':str(item[7]),
                'batteryPower':str(item[8]),
                'solarPower':str(item[9]),
                'loadPower':str(item[10]),
                'batteryCharge':str(item[11])
            }
            items_list.append(i)

        return {'StatusCode':'200$(_id)','Items':items_list}

    except Exception as e:
        return {'error': str(e)}
    api.add_resource(test, '/test')


    if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')

   app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: in `SELECT * FROM \`PowerSystem\` WHERE ID=$(id)` the quotes seem strange. add a `print`, what is the string you actually execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The execute statement is not correct, the pattern should be like `cursor.execute( <select statement string>, <tuple>)`, change your statement to:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `PowerSystem` WHERE ID=%s",(id,))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct and secure way to do it:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM `PowerSystem` WHERE ID=%s", (id))
```